# How can I group by a count of a subvalue of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, counting

I've been trying every combination of `array_count_values` and `array_map` I can think of.  I'm hoping you can show me the way.

Here's a sample array:

```
$arr = array(
            array('name' => 'foo','score' => 1),
            array('name' => 'foo','score' => 2),
            array('name' => 'bar','score' => 1)
        );
```

I'd like to combine the scores of all sub values with the same name.  Something like `GROUP BY name` in MySQL.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => foo
            [score] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => bar
            [score] => 1
        )
)
```

I know there are other questions that sort multidimensional arrays, but I'm not able to find one that sums one of the sub values along the way.

Comment: Just loop through the array and sum accordingly. What's stopping you?

Comment: Do you want first to sort the array with PHP and then insert to the database? Or you want to do this in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_reduce`

```
$arr = array(
        array('name' => 'foo','score' => 1),
        array('name' => 'foo','score' => 2),
        array('name' => 'bar','score' => 1));

$array = array_reduce($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    isset($a[$b['name']]['score']) ? $a[$b['name']]['score'] += $b['score'] : $a[$b['name']] = $b;
    return $a;
});

var_dump($array);
```

Output

```
array
  'foo' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'foo' (length=3)
      'score' => int 3
  'bar' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'bar' (length=3)
      'score' => int 1
```